# Multiple tray icons in Windows 10

Tags: java, trayicon

We have a Java based with some native components and SWT as frontend.

We contribute our tray icon to windows notification area.

Now below is the problem

- If an user is working on the application and then the system goes to sleep/hibernate
- When the system wakes up it has multiple tray icons for the same application.

We have seen it happening for multiple applications. Is it a known issue or are there any workarounds ?

Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

I remember this happening in Windows XP. It's not a new things and has been around for years. I suspect it's a known issue but very low priority and so has never been addressed.

I remember it happening where the software that shows the icon doesn't shut down properly and so the icon it added doesn't get cleared up. You end up with multiple icons where multiple instances of the app have been started but not shut down correctly.
The real solution here would therefore seem to be to build more resilient software that doesn't crash. Obviously debugging hibernation issues can be tricky but I'd start by looking at your own software.

Comment: yes, in earlier windows the false icons used to just disappear when you hover over one of them...but now in Windows  10 they remain...i think as you mention the proper solution would be to check the application shut down logic